# Proper way to indicate code change in lstlisting

Tags: listings

[Since the question was not clear]
I have a piece of program code I would like to describe in my thesis. My problem is that the part I would like to explain is surrounded by simple code pieces not worth to describe. Now I would like to ask, if there is a possibility to have jumps in the line numbers. Further, I would like to ask if someone has experience with indicating that I left out parts of the code because they are not relevant.

```
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Function, label={lst:example}, firstnumber=1]
int complicated_function(int b){
    //I do a lot here..

    if(a < b){
       return a;
    }else{
       return b;
    }
    if(b == 0){ 
        printf("Error");  //Not really relevant, just error handling. How can I leave it out? 
    }
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}`
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please (always) provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that they can use to start building a solution for you.

Comment: I'm not if this is really a question about LaTeX as such. Personally I would typeset the listing as a unified diff, then it should be completely clear. The other option is to have both versions of the code side by side.

Comment: It's not about indicating changes between two versions! I just wanna indicate that the code has more lines but it is not relevant; therefore, I removed them from the lstlsting. But they should know there is more, so i can't just leave it out.

Comment: What about starting the line number close to where your complicated function appears, leaving a bit of code up and down the road into your source listings, and highlighting the important part?

Answer (score 2):

If you want only some lines to be discused in your paper you can easy split the listing in for example three parts, using option `linerange={1-3}` for the first 3 lines. If you want the real line numbers in your listing use for example option `firstnumber=10` to start with line number 10.

Here comes the MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.c}
int complicated_function(int b){
    //I do a lot here..

    if(a < b){
       return a;
    }else{
       return b;
    }
    if(b == 0){ 
        printf("Error");  //Not really relevant, just error handling. How can I leave it out? 
    }
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}               
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  language=c,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  tabsize=2,
  frame=single,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny
}


\begin{document}

We start with 
\lstinputlisting[%
  caption={Function}
 ,label={lst:example}
 ,linerange={1-1}
]{\jobname.c}

Then you will find
\lstinputlisting[%
  caption={Function, Part 2}
 ,label={lst:example2}
 ,linerange={4-8}
]{\jobname.c}

And closing
\lstinputlisting[%
  caption={Function, Part 3}
 ,label={lst:example3}
 ,linerange={10-12}
 ,firstnumber=10
]{\jobname.c}

\end{document}
```

I used package `filecontents` to have one file with the program code to be discussed.